# Как правильно организовать InnerException?

Tags: c#, исключения

Чтобы не писать каждый раз "начать транзакцию", "принять", "откатить", я решил создать метод, в который можно просто передать два действия - одно "основное", а второе - на случай, если в "основном" возникнет ошибка. Но дело в том, что при выполнении "второго" действия тоже может возникнуть ошибка. И хотелось бы как-то эту последовательность сохранить для внешнего обработчика.

Пример: основное действие - сохранение в БД каких-нибудь данных из загруженных файлов. Возникает ошибка - пытаемся файлы удалить, чтобы не занимали место. И например при удалении опять какая-нибудь ошибка. Но теоретически клиентский код может выполнять в транзакции и что-то другое, т.е. я не могу знать, какие именно ошибки возникнут в "основном" и "втором" действии.

Я написал вот такой пример, попытавшись вручную заполнять InnerException, но мне не нравится то, что теряется тип исходного исключения. Т.е. в моем примере `exCatch` является `DivideByZeroException`, а после обработки становится просто `Exception`. Если никак не обрабатывать, то теряется `exTry`. Как-то вручную узнавать тип `exCatch` и создавать исключение такого же типа - ощущается как какой-то костыль.

Как лучше обработать эту ситуацию?

```
class Program
{
    public void TryTransaction(Action tryWork, Action catchWork)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Открыли транзакцию");
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Начинаем выполнять основную работу");
            tryWork();
            Console.WriteLine("Выполнили основную работу");
            Console.WriteLine("Приняли транзакцию");
        }
        catch (Exception exTry)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Откатили транзакцию");
            Console.WriteLine("Начинаем выполнять дополнительную работу");
            try
            {
                catchWork();
            }
            catch (Exception exCatch)
            {
                throw new Exception(exCatch.Message, exTry);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Выполнили дополнительную работу");
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void OkWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Работаем...");
    }

    public void PrimaryWork(int val)
    {
        int result = 5 / val;
    }

    public void AdditionalWork()
    {
        File.Delete(@"C:\tmp\2\NotExistFile.txt");
        Console.WriteLine("Клиентские файлы удалены успешно");
    }
        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var prog = new Program();

        try
        {
            prog.TryTransaction(
                () => prog.PrimaryWork(0), 
                () => prog.AdditionalWork());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            int a = 5;
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: [AggregateException](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=net-5.0).

Comment: Не понимаю как это можно применить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать `AggregateException` - [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=net-5.0).

```cs
class Program
{
    public void TryTransaction(Action tryWork, Action catchWork)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Открыли транзакцию");
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Начинаем выполнять основную работу");
            tryWork();
            Console.WriteLine("Выполнили основную работу");
            Console.WriteLine("Приняли транзакцию");
        }
        catch (Exception exTry)
        {
            List<Exception> exceptions = new List<Exception>();
            exceptions.Add(exTry);
                
            Console.WriteLine("Откатили транзакцию");
            Console.WriteLine("Начинаем выполнять дополнительную работу");
            try
            {
                catchWork();
            }
            catch (Exception exCatch)
            {
                exceptions.Add(exCatch);
                throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Выполнили дополнительную работу");
            throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
        }
    }

    public void OkWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Работаем...");
    }

    public void PrimaryWork(int val)
    {
        int result = 5 / val;
    }

    public void AdditionalWork()
    {
        File.Delete(@"C:\tmp\2\NotExistFile.txt");
        Console.WriteLine("Клиентские файлы удалены успешно");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var prog = new Program();

        try
        {
            prog.TryTransaction(
                () => prog.PrimaryWork(0),
                () => prog.AdditionalWork());
        }
        catch (AggregateException aex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(aex.Message);
            aex.Handle(x => 
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(x.ToString()); 
                return true; 
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

```
Открыли транзакцию
Начинаем выполнять основную работу
Откатили транзакцию
Начинаем выполнять дополнительную работу
One or more errors occurred. (Attempted to divide by zero.) (Could not find a part of the path 'C:\tmp\2\NotExistFile.txt'.)
System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.PrimaryWork(Int32 val) in C:\Source\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 71
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Main>b__0() in C:\Source\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 87
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.TryTransaction(Action tryWork, Action catchWork) in C:\Source\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 39
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\tmp\2\NotExistFile.txt'.
   at System.IO.FileSystem.DeleteFile(String fullPath)
   at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.AdditionalWork() in C:\Source\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 76
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Main>b__1() in C:\Source\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 88
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.TryTransaction(Action tryWork, Action catchWork) in C:\Source\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 52
```

Можно конечно просто `aex.ToString()`, если только для логов, но вы сами пробуйте, как удобнее обработать.

> Т.е. в моем примере `exCatch` является `DivideByZeroException`, а после обработки становится просто `Exception`.

Не становится, вы делаете просто апкаст. Апкаст не меняет тип объекта, а меняет только тип контейнера. Его можно привести к исходному типу обратно:

```cs
if (ex is DivideByZeroException dex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Нельзя делить на ноль");
    Console.WriteLine(dex.ToString());
}
```

Если же хочется просто использовать `ex.InnerException`, то тип внутреннего исключения можно определить так:

```cs
catch (Exception ex)
{
    switch (ex.InnerException)
    {
        case DivideByZeroException inDex:
            // inDex.Message
            break;
        case Exception inEx:
            // inEx.Message
            break;
        default:
            // null
            break;
    }
}
```

---

Как я понял, вам нужно именно засунуть `InnerException` в тело уже выброшенного исключения. Я сам не знаю, но в дотнете это видимо считают своего рода извратом, так как исключение считается неизменяемым. Но когда очень хочется, то есть рефлексия.

```cs
catch (Exception exTry)
{               
    Console.WriteLine("Откатили транзакцию");
    Console.WriteLine("Начинаем выполнять дополнительную работу");
    try
    {
        catchWork();
    }
    catch (Exception exCatch)
    {
        var fi = typeof(Exception).GetField("_innerException", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        fi.SetValue(exCatch, exTry);
        throw;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Выполнили дополнительную работу");
    throw;
}
```

```
Открыли транзакцию
Начинаем выполнять основную работу
Откатили транзакцию
Начинаем выполнять дополнительную работу
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\tmp\2\NotExistFile.txt'.
 ---> System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.PrimaryWork(Int32 val) in C:\Source\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 69
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Main>b__0() in C:\Source\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 85
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.TryTransaction(Action tryWork, Action catchWork) in C:\Source\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 39
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.IO.FileSystem.DeleteFile(String fullPath)
   at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.AdditionalWork() in C:\Source\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 74
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Main>b__1() in C:\Source\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 86
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.TryTransaction(Action tryWork, Action catchWork) in C:\Source\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 49
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Source\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 84
```

Если вам понравился последний вариант, то можно его сделать красиво добавив метод расширения.

```cs
public static class ExceptionTools
{
    private static readonly FieldInfo fi = typeof(Exception).GetField("_innerException", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    public static void SetInnerException(this Exception ex, Exception inner)
    {
        fi.SetValue(ex, inner);
    }
}
```

Тогда код будет выглядеть вот так

```cs
catch (Exception exCatch)
{
    exCatch.SetInnerException(exTry);
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример, теперь понятно. Но мне не очень нравится то, что исключения теперь хранятся в виде списка. Придется в методе логирования отдельно рассматривать случай для типа AggregateException. А в случае с Inner все более единообразно. Насчет второго пункта - имхо все-таки становится. Потому что в блоке catch (Exception exCatch) я создаю обычный Exception и выбрасываю его по сути вместо исходного. Т.е. именно что поймался DivideByZeroException, а выбросился обычный Exception, просто с сообщением исходного.

Comment: @Shebbyman дополнил ответ

Comment: Но что делать, если ответ был полезен, как говорится, "для общего развития", но решение не совсем мне подходит и я хотел бы посмотреть еще, может кто-то предложит другие варианты? А если я его приму, люди подумают, что вопрос решен на 100% и не станут ничего писать. Я дал ему +1.

Comment: @Shebbyman что именно вам не подходит, вы видели, что я снизу дописал?

Comment: Да, видел. Тогда я дополнительно спрошу, а то может такого в природе вообще и не существует: может быть такое, что есть исключение `a`, у него в inner лежит исключение `b`, а в его inner - исключение `c`, у него в inner - `d` и т.д.? Вот я бы такую структуру хотел организовать, если возможно, чтобы единообразно всю цепочку обходить во всех случаях.

Comment: @Shebbyman я еще дополнил вопрос, но я не рекомендую силой запихивать внутреннее исключение в уже выброшенное. Внутреннее исключение можно использовать только для создаваемых исключений, передавая его через конструктор. Если вы хотите пачку исключений обработать, используйте `AggregateException`. Оно как раз и создано, чтобы обойтись без изврата.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Через рефлексию тоже думал сначала сделать, но поминуя слова Павла Майорова, суть которых "Хорошее решение и решение через рефлексию - разные вещи", решил сперва спросить тут.